# How to remove an error message once appended

Tags: jquery

I've got a form field and if that field does not validate, that I append an error to the div, as it wraps the field.  That works fine - however once that error is appended, I can't figure out how to remove it. The validation sets up the error like so:

```
    if(element.attr("name") === "progMax")
{
    error.appendTo("#progMaxWrapper");
}
```

On another part of the form, I can click a radio button and it negates the need for that field.  I can clear and disable the field but the error message remains.

```
if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $("input[name='progMax']").attr({
        'disabled':false
    });
    $('label[for=progMax]').removeClass('radioLabelDisabled');
    ??????? error.remove();  <=====  Not sure what to do here to remove the error appended above ========
}
```

I've seen similar examples but nothing I've found has worked or I'm too new at this to modify it successfully. Hopefully this is clear - if not, my apologies.

Comment: Do you have to use appendTo for this? Can't you just add another div inside #progMaxWrapper and change its inner html? Also can you post your html fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to remove the part you have added, it should have an id or a class to identify it. So if you are appending something like

```
$( "<p>Test</p>" ).appendTo( ".inner" );
```

you can not remove it with that function. But if you append something like

```
$( "<p id='error_div'>Test</p>" ).appendTo( ".inner" );
```

then you can remove it with a call like.

```
$( "#error_div" ).remove();
```

For more information on the usage of the function, check out the API reference on [remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Comment: I do that now as a result of this little quirk - just didn't for this first one.  I could just spend a few minutes and add a span or something that I could add an id to and that would do it.  I was just curious if I was missing something or if there was a way to make it work as is.  Now I have my answer.  Thanks!